# Simple(r) Excel formula to calculate forward stock (inventory) cover

Tags: excel, excel-formula

This is a perennial question for retailers, for which there are a number of solutions in existence:

How can you calculate the "forward cover" of a product knowing its current inventory and armed with forward sales estimates.

eg.

- current inventory 100 units (cell A1)
- weekly forward sales estimates: 25, 30, 10, 40, 90... (in range
  A2:AX)

Here the answer would be 3.875 weeks (3 full weeks plus 0.875 of week 4)

I have a UDF to do this already.
I also have some slightly complicated array functions to do this, eg.

```
=MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2:A13,,,ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2)+1))>A1,0)-1+(A1-SUM(A2:INDEX(A2:A13,MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2:A13,,,ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2)+1))>A1,0)-1)))/INDEX(A2:A13,MATCH(TRUE,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(A2:A13,,,ROW(A2:A13)-ROW(A2)+1))>A1,0)-1+1)
```

I was wondering if there is a neater way with these 'new-fangled' array functions which have been available for the last few years in later versions of Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=LET(inv,A1,
     sales,A2:A6,
     cs,SCAN(0,sales,LAMBDA(x,y,x+y)),
     m,XMATCH(A1,cs,1)-1,
m+(inv-
   IF(m=0,
          0,
          INDEX(cs,m)))
   /INDEX(sales,m+1))
```

SCAN() is perfect for creating a cumulative sum.

It can be referenced inside XMATCH because of the use of LET.

Here m returns the number of full weeks and the final calculation is the number of full weeks + (inv- cumulative sum up to the full week)/sales of the following week.

Comment: This looks great. I’ve not had a chance to try it yet so will report back Monday :-) never even heard of the SCAN function

Comment: I find this a good explanation of how it works: https://exceljet.net/functions/scan-function#:~:text=Like%20the%20REDUCE%20function%2C%20SCAN,returns%20an%20array%20of%20values.

Comment: Yes, this is perfect - and wins the prize for conciseness! I have so much to learn...

Answer (score 4):

Here is another possible solution, although it requires the `LET()` function which is only available to newer version of excel (2021, 365 and later I believe).

The solution would be the following formula:

```
=LET(
    sales,A2:A50,
    inventory,A1,
    cum_sum,MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(sales),1,0),(ROW(sales)<=TRANSPOSE(ROW(sales)))*sales),
    week_full,MATCH(TRUE,inventory<cum_sum,0) - 1,
    week_frac,(inventory - INDEX(cum_sum,week_full)) / INDEX(sales,week_full + 1),
    week_full + week_frac
)
```

### Explanation

Given inventory and the forward looking sales estimates, the formula calculates the running total (i.e. cumulated sum) of the sales estimates as shown in the table here below

| Inv and Sales | Cumulated Sum | Inv > Cum_Sum | Week |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 |  |  |  |
| 25 | 25 | 0 | 1 |
| 30 | 55 | 0 | 2 |
| 10 | 65 | 0 | 3 |
| **40** | **105** | **1** | **4** |
| 90 | 195 | 1 | 5 |
| ... | ... | 1 | 6 |

The formula goes on to get the number of full weeks of 'forward cover' by finding the the value for the cumulated sum that exceeds the inventory minus one (here 4 - 1 = 3).

Lastly, for the value of the week fraction covered in the last week, the formula calculates inventory minus sum of sales estimates of all previous weeks divided by sales estimate of final week of cover (i.e. (100 - 65) / 40 = 0.875).

### Edit

After simplifying the formula you used with the `LET()` function, I noticed it's doing exactly the same calculation with the only difference of how the cumulated sum is being calculated. Here's your formula using `LET()`:

```
=LET(
    sales,A2:A50,
    inventory,A1,
    cum_sum,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(sales,,,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sales)))),
    week_full,MATCH(TRUE,cum_sum>inventory,0)-1,
    week_frac,(inventory - INDEX(cum_sum,week_full)) / INDEX(sales,week_full+1),
    week_full + week_frac
)
```

Comment: This is great - thank you. Just what I was hoping for: not just 'an answer' but a good illustration to show how to use functions like LET. As an Excel user of several decades now you get used to using the same old functions... always with the nagging doubt there's a better way!

Comment: happy I could help. Not only does the LET() funciton give more clarity to the formula, but it also speeds up calculation. The 'variables' declared in the functions only store the value of their calculation, meaning, whenever that variable is called in subsequent calculations, it doesn't have to be recalculated.

Comment: So in the previous version of your formula the MATCH(...,SUBTOTAL(...)) calculation appeared 3 times and, hence, was calculated 3 times. With the LET() functions it is only calculated once.

Comment: This will spill wrong results if the inventory is smaller than the first sales. Can be avoided using `=LET(
    sales,A2:A50,
    inventory,A1,
    cum_sum,SUBTOTAL(9,OFFSET(sales,,,SEQUENCE(ROWS(sales)))),
    week_full,MATCH(TRUE,cum_sum>inventory,0)-1,
    week_frac,(inventory - IF(week_full=0,0,INDEX(cum_sum,week_full))) / INDEX(sales,week_full+1),
    week_full + week_frac
)`

Comment: @P.b good catch, thanks for highlighting